# Change Windows Store Apps language using poweshell or unattend.xml?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, sysprep, settings, user-settings

I am trying to create a golden image and I can't find any way to set Store Apps language.

These are the settings I want:

Windows Display: English (US)
Apps & Websites: English (US)
Regional Format: Turkish
Keyboard: Turkish
Speech: English(US)

These are the language/region settings in my unattend.xml:

```
        <InputLocale>tr-TR;en-US</InputLocale>
        <SystemLocale>tr-TR</SystemLocale>
        <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
        <UserLocale>tr-TR</UserLocale>
```

But after the sysrep, App language setting changes to Turkish, I tried to change UserLocale in unattended.xml to en-US too but got the same result plus region changed to US.

We are going to image a lot of computers and while it's not difficult to go to the Settings app and change those settings, it would be nice to have it sorted out with a script.

Is there any way to achieve this with powershell or a registry tweak?